# Purchasing ticket for my dog

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings, pets

Can I purchase a seat for my 25 lb.American Eskimo dog to go to Europe on a economy class?

Comment: Which airline? Or are you asking if any airlines support this? Where from? Canada? USA? Other?

Comment: +1, great question, be sure to read what the Telegraph has to say about it.  http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/travel-advice/10759585/Travelling-to-Europe-with-a-pet-rules-and-advice.html

Comment: Of possible interest: *[Which airlines allow in-cabin pets on transatlantic flights?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2869)* and *[Experience travelling with small pets in the cabin during transatlantic flights?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37177)*

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot take a 25 lb dog in cabin on flights to Europe.

[The UK specifically bans in-cabin dogs](http://www.heathrow-airport-guide.co.uk/pet-travel.html) as part of their quarantine requirements, but [all other carriers have a weight limit (generally dog plus container) less than the weight of your dog](http://www.dogjaunt.com/guides/international-airline-pet-policies-for-in-cabin-travel/), topping out at around the 6-8 kg or 13-18 lb mark.  More references [here](http://www.dogfriendly.com/server/travel/airtravel/airpettravelintl.shtml).